How to understand 'Worst Best' in 'The Worst Best Economy Ever'?
From The Atlantic

The Worst Best Economy Ever.
Why Biden is getting no credit for the boom.

The journalist seems to say 'the worst economy ever', but what does 'best' mean?

"Worst best" may seem a contradiction in terms, and often it is used that way either for comic effect or to make a satirical point. However, it could be perfectly normal in specific contexts. It's not uncommon to hear the phrase "the best of the best" (or, as the French say, la crème de la crème), so if you can have a "best best" it stands to reason you can have a worst best.
Say, for example, that every country entered their "best" athlete in a competition. Each country's own 'best' competes against each other. The winner of that contest could be called "the best of the best", so the loser is arguably the worst of the best.
As I understand the article you are asking about, America currently has "the strongest economy the United States has ever experienced". Of course, "best" is always relative - if this is the current best, other periods would have been 'the best' at the time. However, the article goes on to say that despite the numbers on paper 'proving' the economy is doing well, public perception is different. So, out of every economical period that America has ever called "the best", this is the worst of that set. That is why it is the worst "best" economy.
